# Не подсвечивается sass синтаксис в Sublime Text

Tags: css, sublime-text, sass

Установил Ruby, потом делал по инструкции через командную строку:

1. gem install sass
2. gem install compass
3. d:
4. cd FrontEnd - папка моего проекта
5. compass init

   Все эти операции проделал, появились папки, файлы в моем проекте. Зашел в папку sass/screen.scss и тут возникли проблемы, Sublime видит его как обычный блокнотовский документ, то есть расширение scss открыто через "All Files" - искал расширение .scss - не нашел. Что я только не пробовал делать, не получается исправить эту проблему.
   Вышлю для наглядности скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

для подстветки нужен плагин Sass для сублайма
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sass